# To solve $ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+b+c}=1$ in natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

I really stuck on the following 7th grade problem (shame on me).

The problem asks to solve an equation in natural numbers (that is to find all possible such natural  $a,b,c~$ that) 
 $$ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+b+c}=1$$ 
I have found solutions: $$a=3, ~b=0, ~c=0;$$ $$a=2, ~b=1, ~c=3$$ and $$a=2, ~b=2, ~c=0$$
but there must be a general trick to find all possible solutions, that I missed.

**Can anyone suggest some way to solve the equation?**

Comment: $a=1,b=0,c=0$ is not a solution.

Comment: You mean $a = 3$ in first example.

Comment: Note that $a>3$ is impossible.  Thus we have $a\in \{1,2,3\}$ and just go case by case.

Comment: I think after a point, the solutions become too small to sum up to $1$.

Comment: 0 is not a natural number.

Comment: Oh I got point thanks  to all!!! Yeh first example is typo

Comment: @ManishKundu $\mathbb{N}$ very often does include $0$ - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\frac 1a$ is the largest of the three fractions so must be at least $\frac 13$.

The admissible values for $a$ are then $1, 2, 3$.

If $a=3$ you have $b=c=0$ or the total will be less than $1$.

If $a=2$ then you have $\cfrac 1{2+b}+\cfrac 1{2+b+c}=\cfrac 12$ and the largest fraction must be at least $\frac 14$.

Then consider what happens when $a=1$

Answer (score 0):

$$1=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+b+c}\geq\frac{3}{a+b+c},$$ which gives
$$a+b+c\leq3$$ and since $a\geq2$, we obtain two easy cases.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned equation shown below has parametric solution given below:

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+b+c}=1$

$(a,b,c) =[w(-1-k),w(1+2k),w(k)]$

where,  $w=(k+3)/[2k(k+1)]$

---